# unity plugins conflict in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I imported two plugins to unity 5.they both need to have their own application in AndroidManifest.xml.
I can't initialize them from code.
do you have any idea what should i do?

Comment: As far as I know, every time you try to use two or more plugins the manifest becomes a mess or even worse! it gets overwrite.

So you need to check both manifest files in your plugins and try to merge them both into one file.

I not sure about yours but most of the plugins comes with a guide to merge them and make it work with others.

Comment: Tanks for your comment.
The problem is i can't merge them because both of them have their own "android:name" in "application" tag and i don't allow to use two application tag in AndroidManifest.xml!

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't offer you more help witouth an example of your manifest files, but it souldn't be a trouble if each manifest contains his own activity for each plugin except in the case the plugin says the oposite.